# MySQL: Searching one simple table, but combining the WordPress 'wp_usermeta' table with meta_key/meta_value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

As I mention in the title, I'm doing a request for latitude and longitude within a 'bid_userloc' table ... but I need to combine information from the 'wp_usermeta' table ...

```
SET @centerLat = '48.531157';
SET @centerLng = '-123.782959';

SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @centerLat ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(@centerLng) ) + sin( radians( @centerLat ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM bid_userloc HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

And using the `user_id` that comes in from the `SELECT *`, I need to get some user data from the `wp_userdata` table that looks like this:

```
id
meta_key
meta_value
```

For example, I need the `meta_value` of `meta_key` "nickname" ... as well as a number of others, but once I see how it's done for one, I can add more.

I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, with distance replaced with what you originally had, and something else replaced with something real:

```
SET @centerLat = '48.531157';
SET @centerLng = '-123.782959';

SELECT bid_userloc.*, distance, nickname.meta_value, something_else.meta_value
FROM bid_userloc
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS nickname 
    ON nickname.userid = bid_userloc.user_id 
        AND nickname.meta_key = 'nickname'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS something_else 
    ON something_else.userid = bid_userloc.user_id 
        AND something_else.meta_key = 'something_else'
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Comment: Thanks for this Calle... however, the "distance" declaration seems to be giving an issue. `distance` only exists because of the forumla ... it's not in the database anywhere.

Comment: I figured it out. I'll post it as an answer... THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

The modified answer is the follow:

```
SET @centerLat = '48.531157';
SET @centerLng = '-123.782959';

SELECT bid_userloc.*, nickname.meta_value, last_name.meta_value,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @centerLat ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(@centerLng) ) + sin( radians( @centerLat ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM bid_userloc
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS nickname 
    ON nickname.user_id = bid_userloc.user_id 
        AND nickname.meta_key = 'nickname'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS last_name 
    ON last_name.user_id = bid_userloc.user_id 
        AND last_name.meta_key = 'last_name'
HAVING distance < 25
LIMIT 0 , 20
```